# How much time one should give to worhsipping /meditating upon god?

Tags: bhakti

According to Gita , Karma Yog and Bhakti Yog should be combinely pursued.
My question is how much time one should give to worshiping god or meditation upon god and devote rest of out time in Karma Yoga (doing worldy tasks).
Is there anywhere mentioned in scriptures like how much time ?

Comment: All the time, if possible 

Comment: @Adiyarkku All the time is quite hard(it becomes mechanical at times with no real bhakti bhava) so I don't think no of hours matter(for later stages of intense sadhana they do obvio), but what matters more is Quality and CONSISTENCY(from personal exp).No matter what the situation arises you HAVE to do fixed number of rounds, at a fixed time, at a fixed place as i think dedication and sincerity in bhakti is what causes rapid progress towards developing an intimate connection with the devata and attracts his grace faster....

Comment: @Rāmachandra yes. Ab prabhu kripa karahu ehi bhaanti sab taji bhajan karaun din raati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bhagavad Gita 6.3 answers this question.

> For a sage, who is desirous of mounting upon the (Dhyana)Yoga, action(karma/bhakti yog) is said to be the cause; for the same [sage], when he has mounted upon the (Dhyana)Yoga, quietude is said to be the cause..
>  Swami Gambirananda

Upon culmination of karma/bhakti yoga , it is innate for a yogi to indulge exclusively in Bhagavad dhyana.So It is natural for a yogi to seek solitude, over the charms of worldly affairs ,for He is the one ,who has evolved ..
How much time does it take to achieve this state of mind may differ across  individual aspirants.

PS: Indulging in  any Karma with Ishwara(Bhagavad) arpana buddhi, is Karma yoga. Here the attitude with which any karma is done matters. Neither It is about allocation of time for Puja(Yet Puja Vidhi *kala ,when should it be done eg. Pradosha kala etc..is according to shaastras as in another ans* ) Nor Its about seeking peace/silence outside.Karma yoga is a matter of remaining calm inside amidst of swirl of activities, when will the karmayog culminate cannot be fitted in a time frame. It could be a janmantara(across janmas) endeavour.

Answer (score 1):

The time you should devote is a personal preference - You should devote time according to your `Gati and Mati`. There are devatas which are required to be prayed only at a specific time and after/before a ritual. Like Suryanarayan Bhagwan must only be prayed early in the morning after a bath. As you have mentioned - Geeta, I will answer your question in Vaishnav Sampradaya context.
First of all, whichever deity you pray,

> भक्ति शास्त्र सम्मत होनी चाहिए|

You should not bend to praying with your own methods, rather ask you pandits, brahman's, Pushti Marga sevaks, and Vaishya's. If you are chanting mantras, be precise in that because a mismatch in `swar and uccharan` will lead to `real harm`.

In Vaishnav sampradaya, it is mentioned in the Bhagwat Purana and Geeta that, you can chant Narayan Naam anywhere anytime, it will bring you good. It is to believed that Bhagwat Geeta is written after the Vedas, and it is actually `saar` of the Vedas. So if you are doing `jap` of Narayan naam, you can do that any time.
It may not be the answer to your question, but it's all that i know of.

Reference - [Ajamil, and his son Narayana, in Bhagwat Purana.](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/the-power-of-the-lord-s-name---the-story-of-ajamil)